# If $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} z_n=z_0$ and $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} w_n=w_0$, then $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} (\sum z_kw_{n-k})=z_0w_0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

If $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} z_n=z_0$ and $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} w_n=w_0$, prove $$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\big( \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n} z_kw_{n-k}\big) = z_{0}w_{0}$$
$z_n,w_n\in \mathbb{C}$

I've seen this problem of the actual number version in mathematical analysis. Now, I meet it again in complex analysis. Should I prove that the module and argument are equal separately?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/725914/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/102727/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/936903/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/876520/42969

Comment: Remember that $r_n\exp\{\textbf{i}\theta_n\}=z_n\to z=r\exp\{\textbf{i}\theta\}$ does not imply $\theta_n\to\theta$

Comment: Those questions may be about *real* sequences, but most proofs (such as https://math.stackexchange.com/a/727180/42969) work for complex sequences as well.

Comment: Try to prove it in an arbitrary [normed algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_algebra). It is cumbersome to prove it in several special cases.